# Paying for expensive, relatively slow WAN link between virtually adjacent offices. Alternatives?

Tags: ethernet, wan

A few years ago, I worked for a corporation which payed quite a lot (I forgot exactly how much but it was quite a few hundred dollars per month) for a WAN link to connect two adjacent offices.

The offices were in a quiet industrial complex, probably no more than 100 ft apart (with just a virtually empty car park between them). There were no other office buildings in between, meaning there was 100% unobstructed line of site between the two facilities.

The speed of this WAN link was, I believe, only around 5 Mbps - something which frequently caused a bottleneck when these two sites attempted to do large file transfers.

I have often wondered what cheaper and/or faster alternatives could have been used in this situation and always found it incredible that they had to pay a monthly fee to a 3rd party, just to slowly transfer data between very close main offices. A simple CAT5 cable could have saved the company hundreds of dollars per month and provided speeds over 100x faster than what they were getting.

Is it normal for businesses to pay for WAN links in this sort of situation? Was a WAN link probably the only viable option? What about running Ethernet or fibre through a conduit between the rooftops (30 ft off the ground) or even using microwave Ethernet?

If there was no way to get a legal easement to run an Ethernet or fibre cable between the rooftops (as they did not own the land in between), then what argument could be made against using a microwave Ethernet link to bridge the gap?

Looking forward to hearing everyone's thoughts!

Comment: This is an interesting question but it is attracting close votes because it's written very opinion-based and as a "brainstorming" question.  Can you rephrase it to better fit the site model?

Comment: Yoda: "Do or Do not. There is no try."  Sorry, couldn't resist.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Quick Brainstorm (partially backed by previous epxerience):

- Microdish communication
- Site-Site VPN over Fibre Internet
- Cat6/Fibreunderground or overground (subject to permission)
- high powered WiFi Repeater

I once worked for a college who got permission to use a streetlight for a wireless repeater between buildings that were a few hundred feet apart on the provision that they provided public WiFi through it.  They did this by creating a dedicated VLAN and assigning it 100kbps web only traffic and kept the rest for themselves